# I3 with HiDPI dispkay

Tags: fonts, display-resolution, i3-wm, hdpi

I am using i3vm with a display with 2560x1440 resolution. The issues is that all the fonts are small, and I don't have a clear idea on how to solve this problem.

I am loocking for a global solution, and now i have found just "local" fixes. For instance, i have increased the font size of the i3 components.

But things like firefox really are too small to be used. Nt only the icons of the app are small as in other applications, but also the websites needs to be zoomed up to 150% to become "normal". How would you solve this problem?
I am documenting about the following options, but I'm not sure about the real cause of the problem.

- changing the scale of the display with xrandr (not working in command line, maybe i should do it before X starts..)
- changing the dpi (and revert the i3 configurtaion to its previous status, i guess): not working either from command line.
- Obviously calling the "Unity  twak tool" from i3 is not working...

Comment: Have you tried using ```XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity; unity-control-center``` (I'm assuming you're using unity ubuntu, but it could be changed to gnome if not) to access the control center and try to adjust the global font-size using accessibility perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file: `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and add a line like this to define the font and size to use:

`gtk-font-name="Archivo,  14"`

depending on the app you may need to update the setting here too: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

`gtk-font-name=Noto Sans,  10`